# NodeJS Twitter API client returns different next_cursor and next_cursor_str values

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-follow

I am working with Twitter API ( in Node ) and trying to get the followers. As Twitter as has added cursor in its response I am easily getting first 20 followers but as soon as I try to update my cursor it redirects me to the first page. Need help to update the cursor.

```
var cursor = -1;

mainEmployee( params, cursor );

function mainEmployee( params, cursor ) {
  console.log(cursor);

  var url = 'followers/list.json?count=5000&' + cursor;
  console.log( url );
  client.get(url, params, function(error, followers, response ) {
    if( !error ) {
      // console.log( cursor );
      // for( var i = 0; i < followers.users.length; i++ ) {
      //    followersData( followers.users[i] );        
      // }
      // console.log( followers );
      var new_cursor = followers.next_cursor_str;

      if( cursor != 0)
        mainEmployee(params, new_cursor);
      else
        console.log("cursor is empty");
    }
    else {
        console.log( error );
    }
  });
}
```

[image: I am also getting different next_cursor and next_cursor_str value]

I am also getting different `next_cursor` and `next_cursor_str` value.

Please suggest me what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of an undefined `cursor` parameter. The [Twitter API documentation for cursors](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring) defines routes with cursors like this:

> url_with_cursor = api_path + "&cursor=" + cursor

The route must have `&cursor=` at the end.

You should refactor the `url` to define a cursor:

```
var url = 'followers/list.json?count=5000&cursor=' + cursor;
```

Comment: Thanks @gnerkus I got my mistake

Comment: You're welcome. Could you select this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem? It will help future visitors to this question.